# Get difference between first and last measure values in a date range - MDX

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, olap

I want to get the first value and last value of a selected measure between a specified date range. 
Example: 
If I have a query that returns values between 10 Nov and 17 Nov, I want to subtract the value at 17 Nov from the value at 10 Nov.
I tried using `tail()` and `head()` functions but it still not working.

Comment: so in other words you need only rows containing first and last values on a particular column?

Comment: @EduardUta No, The difference between them, and then I will get top count of 10 values based on the difference.

Comment: You need to provide us some additional info concerning the schema of your table. Give us some sample data as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(t.Col) - MIN(t.Col)
FROM yourTable t
```

The statement returns the difference between max and min values on column Col. The statement can be further used as a subquery in various clauses such as where or select. 
If the column Col is a date-related one then the difference computed will reflect the number of days between min an max.

Comment: Please include an explanation of your code.  It's unlikely to be helpful to the asker without an explanation.